# angular4 http headers , How to set up?

Tags: angular

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions,  } from '@angular/http';
@Injectable()
export class RoleService {
    headers = new Headers({"Content-Type": "application/json"});
     options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
     constructor(private http: Http) {  }

    getRoleList(data) {
         return this.http.post('http://192.168.10.178:9080/role/getRole', data, this.options)
                .toPromise()
                .then(res => res.json().data)
                .then(data => { return data; });
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPiK8.png

Help me!! How to solve this ???

Comment: Please include a clear question, what are the issues, what is the result, etc ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
export class RoleService {
  options: RequestOptions;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    let headers: any = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  }

// ........
```

Comment: error: Property 'append' does not exist on type 'Headers'.

Comment: @yanWu try changing `headers: Headers;` to `headers: any;`

Comment: wa~~~You're awesome!!  Thanks

Comment: @yanWu If it works, then I think the `Property 'append' does not exist on type 'Headers'` error is the typescript compiler error.. Glad it works btw :)

Comment: sorry,I found another problem!    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';    error:Cannot use imports, exports, or module augmentations when '--module' is 'none'.   What happened??

Comment: @yanWu I believe that is a different issue, some fix to the `tsconfig.json` may help: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin/issues/270.. try adding the `"files"` in the `tsconfig.json`.. Or try specifying `"module"` in the `tsconfig.json`..

Answer (score 0):

Its might be fix your issue

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions,  } from '@angular/http';
@Injectable()
export class RoleService {
     constructor(private http: Http) {  }

    getRoleList(data) {
     let headers = new Headers({"Content-Type": "application/json"});
     let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
         return this.http.post('http://192.168.10.178:9080/role/getRole', data, this.options)
                .toPromise()
                .then(res => res.json().data)
                .then(data => { return data; });
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the version of Angular 4.3, `HttpClientModule` was introduced along with `HttpClient`, `HttpHeaders`, `HttpParams` and `HttpRequest` and some of the method has been deprecated such as `RequestOptions`.

You can use `HttpClientModule` from `@angular/common/http`.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpRequest, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient){}
    headers = new HttpHeaders({"Content-Type": "application/json"});

    callAPI(){
         return this.http.get(URL,{headers}).subscribe(data=>{
             console.log(data);
         });
    }
}
```

You can also refer :- https://angular.io/api/common/http/